# Get domain name of incoming connection

Tags: java, c++, sockets, domain-name

I don't find any information on this topic on the internet and asked here. For example I have server with IP 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 and two domain names pointing to it one.example.com and example2.net, and socke listening on port 1234 for incoming connections.

For example:

C/C++:

```
listenfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(...);
listen(...);
while(...) accept(...);
```

or Java:

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(1234);
while(...) {
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    ...
}
```

When client accepted on my socket I need to know what domain name/IP is used by the client to connect. It may be one.example.com or example2.net and/or IP 1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2 (if connected using IP only).

Apache somehow determined ip/domain of incoming reques, and I need to do such thing in pure socket code. C++ (main) or Java (or any other) accepted, I need to know mechaniics of this.

Comment: Apache knows the domain that's being addressed because it's included in the HTTP header. You haven't said what you're doing, so this might not be an option for you.

Comment: Yes I deal with HTTP, so this option is mine. Alongide with Paweł Stawarz's answer it solves my problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP is stored inside the [IP packet header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and you can read it from there. In order to get the host, you'll probably have to ask a DNS server by sending a [request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Protocol_details) (or use a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564525/resolve-ip-to-hostname) which does it for you). You can find examples for both of the problems, even on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298793/read-raw-socket-ip-header-c)